# Spring registerBeanDefinition throws java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: spring

We have following piece of code that gets called multiple times. The issue is it is throwing java.util.ConcurrentModificationException once in 100 requests

```
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;
    boolean beanDefExists = registry.containsBeanDefinition(beanName);
    if (!beanDefExists) {
        BeanDefinitionBuilder beanDefBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(clazz);
        beanDefBuilder.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE);
        beanDefBuilder.setLazyInit(false);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
    }
```

```
13:18:10,728 INFO  [stdout] (http-executor-threads - 33) java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
13:18:10,728 INFO  [stdout] (http-executor-threads - 33)        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
13:18:10,729 INFO  [stdout] (http-executor-threads - 33)        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
13:18:10,729 INFO  [stdout] (http-executor-threads - 33)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resetBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:714) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
13:18:10,729 INFO  [stdout] (http-executor-threads - 33)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:675) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Can someone please provide a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that two requests come in at the same time and they both want to register a bean. To see what happens, we must look at the source code of [`DefaultListableBeanFactory`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/3.2.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.java). In the method `registerBeanDefinition(...)` there is a synchronized block, where the two threads wait for each other to finish. But right after the block the method `resetBeanDefinition(...)` is called. So when the first thread finishes with the synchronized block and continues inside the reset method, the second thread goes on executing the synchronized block. The first thread goes on to loop through the collection `beanDefinitionNames` (line 714), while in the meantime the second thread adds a bean name to the list (line 669). So you get an exception.

If both threads want to create the same bean, then you obviously want to create only one and reuse it, so you have to put the code in a synchronized block. That way only one thread creates the bean and the other can already use it. On the other hand, if both threads create different beans, only the `registerBeanDefinition` method needs to be synchronized.

```
synchronized(this) {
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;
    boolean beanDefExists = registry.containsBeanDefinition(beanName);
    if (!beanDefExists) {
        BeanDefinitionBuilder beanDefBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(clazz);
        beanDefBuilder.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE);
        beanDefBuilder.setLazyInit(false);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Found the real reason for the exception, the solution is still the same.

Comment: Why do you think `containsBeanDefinition` runs in its own thread?

Comment: Where did I say that? :)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. What thread are you talking about here: _So if you hit the right moment you will add a bean to the collection while another thread is iterating through it._?

Comment: What I meant is, that another request comes in, which runs in its own thread - I guess it's a web application.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Does that mean BeanDefinitionRegistry methods are not Thread Safe?

Comment: You should investigate which class is behind that interface in your case (`BeanDefinitionRegistry` is just an interface). I see that for example `SimpleBeanDefinitionRegistry` contains a `ConcurrentHashMap`, so it should be thread-safe. On second thought, maybe this isn't your cause of problems, but still it is the only one I can see.

Comment: It is org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory. Actually this is the class that is getting injected by the container. It doesnt use a ConcurrentHashMap but it is synchronizing the code in registerBeanDefinition.

Comment: Look at the edited answer - I wrote the reason why the exception is thrown. I also reported the bug to Spring https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12503

Comment: Thanks Lovro again.I will be following the jira created.

Comment: No problem, I hope you resolve your problem. I don't mean to be pushy, but you could mark my answer as accepted, since I think it answers your question - a few reputation points don't hurt :-)